# Registering ApplicationDbContext with hierarchical lifetime manager

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, owin, unity-container

I'm starting from an out-of-the-box MVC5 installation and Unity as an IoC container.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web;
using DemoAPI.Repository;
using DemoMVC.Controllers;
using DemoMVC.Models;
using Unity;
using Unity.AspNet.Mvc;
using Unity.Injection;
using Unity.Lifetime;

namespace DemoMVC
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the Unity configuration for the main container.
    /// </summary>
    public static class UnityConfig
    {
        #region Unity Container
        private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container =
          new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
          {
              var container = new UnityContainer();
              RegisterTypes(container);
              return container;
          });

        /// <summary>
        /// Configured Unity Container.
        /// </summary>
        public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the type mappings with the Unity container.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="container">The unity container to configure.</param>
        /// <remarks>
        /// There is no need to register concrete types such as controllers or
        /// API controllers (unless you want to change the defaults), as Unity
        /// allows resolving a concrete type even if it was not previously
        /// registered.
        /// </remarks>
        public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
        {

            container.RegisterType<IRepository, DemoRepository>();  

            #region OWIN
            container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());
            container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>,
                UserStore<ApplicationUser>>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationManager>(
                new InjectionFactory(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication));
            container.RegisterType<ApplicationSignInManager>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
            #endregion



        }
    }
}
```

I have one major worry here: Registering ApplicationDbContext with hierarchical lifetime manager. Manually registering DbContext and using this instance when registering the rest of the types - seems fishy to use the same eternal db context for ALL requests. However, per request makes even less sense for me, as it seems a huge waste of resources to instantiate dbContext per every request.

Is there another/better way to do this that I might be missing? I tried looking up the docs for unity and particularly lifetime managers, but everything I could find seems fairly outdated.

Comment: Why creating a new instance of the context for each request would be a waste? FYI, this is what ASP.NET Core does out of the box, and it works quite great. Also, if you are worried about out of date stuff, leave MVC 5 behind